# A valid changelogDate is required to parse. JHIPSTER Date field

Tags: jhipster, yeoman-generator

I am facing an issue while creating an Entity from the <Entity>.json file using command

```
jhipster entity Customer --skip-install --force
```

My .json file changelogDate and fieldType is as below

```
"changelogDate": "1631210561484","fieldType": "LocalDate",
```

It's showing the below error

> Error: Copying template C:\Users\dsamarli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\entity-server\templates\src\main\resources\config\liquibase\fake-data\table.csv.ejs failed.
> A valid changelogDate is required to parse.

**When I update the json after removing the dateOfBirth field, it works fine.**

where changelogDate is being used for date field type. I am not sure why the changelogDate present in my json file is not valid. I am generating it via this line "" + new Date().getTime()

Comment: What do you mean by `I am generating it via this line "" + new Date().getTime()`? Are you modifying the generator or writing a blueprint or a module? If you did not modify anthing, you should open an issue on JHipster's github project and give more details including output of `jhipster info`

Comment: So I've written a script, which collects the value such as fieldtypes, relationships, pagination etc and create the Entity.json which also has a key changeLogDate whose value I am generating by "" + new Date().getTime() i.e.  "changelogDate": new Date().getTime(). On running jhipster entity Entity, this pre-created json is used to create or update the entity. But just now I removed this "changelogDate" key and ran it. The console printed the below line. WARNING! changelogDate is missing in .jhipster/Customer.json, using 20210910061944 as fallback. And the entity got updated. is it correct way?

Comment: By generating <Entity>.json, you are by-passing many validations that are applied by the generator and so could create errors. I would rather generate JDL for this. The changelogDate is used to check whether the entity should be updated. Also by generating entity JSON, you can't get any support from JHipster team

Comment: Ya Gael, we are exploring it as of now. We will be switching to JDL soon but as the existing platform is using scripts, so we are refining it a bit.

Comment: We have tried to take care of most of the validations that are provided by the generator by creating new applications, new entities from cmd itself, have gone through the features provided, questions asked on application creation. Yes we must have missed some, we are exploring it and we'll try to use as many features we can from the jhipster generator itself. But as of now we are bound to use the script for the platform we are working on. We'll be switching to JDL but will need some time.